# Connecting signals without node and through node of a child - Godot

Tags: class, nodes, godot, gdscript

What I've been trying to do so far -

I have a class Singleton script called `recipes`. I have a signal `launched` in it. I have objects of the `recipe` class. One of the objects is `noodles`. I want to connect the signal `launched` to a function in noodles called `after_launch`. I am not sure what node to connect the signal to.  I am using a class because I have multiple `recipes`, each having its own `launched` signal.

I also want to know how to connect a signal to a function in a Singleton Script - without having nodes at all.

Code I've been using for the same -

```
connect("launched", self, "launched_noodle")
```

I do understand that using "connect" without using a node in front of it gives an error. 
Error -

> error(3,1) Unexpected token Identifier:connect

How do I -

**1) Connect it to the node on which the code is written on - w.r.t  `recipes` and `noodles`. What nodes do you generally connect your signals to?**

**2) Connect when I just want to connect it to the Singleton Script.**

I tried to Google the problem and came across [this question on Godot Forum](https://godotengine.org/qa/43358/create-signals-in-code-without-having-node-in-scene) for a similar issue. I don't understand the full question or answer. Perhaps might be a help for you to refer to.

Additional Information -

Code of my class (Singleton)`recipe`

```
extends Node2D
class_name recipe
signal launched
```

Code of `noodles` and other children -

```
extends recipe
connect("launched", self, "launched_noodle")
```

**The flow of Code -**

User triggers the`cooking station` and the `cooking station` node opens up on the screen.

After that, the user's level and other parameters are checked and an appropriate `recipe` is shown on the screen. This `recipe` is a defined `class` - a Godot Singleton - and has many physical nodes linked under `cooking station`

Once the appropriate node is targetted and shown on the screen, the `signal` that I wanted to launch should be emitted by `cooking station`. This `signal` - depending on the node is it emitted on, makes certain changes on the screen. That is through a function named `launched_recipename`

Comment: "I have a class Singleton script called recipes" ... "I have multiple recipes". These statements seem contradictory. A singleton, by definition, has one instance. Also, please share your complete code. That error sounds like a syntax error.

Comment: Hi. My Singleton is a class, and it has many children. I have added the additional code as requested.

Comment: Extending a Singleton class to create non-singleton nodes is a pretty bizarre pattern to me. Can you take a step back and explain what you're actually trying to accomplish at a high level?

Comment: I'm trying to create a system where there is a cooking station with multiple nodes of recipes. All of them are hidden and the one that matches the player's level and certain other parameters is shown on the screen. All the recipes have standard functions - so I made a class which is accessible to all the nodes - hence in a singleton script. I extended the class to all the nodes in my screen, as the variables values of all the nodes are different, even though variable names are same. Similarly, I also want a signal that is common to all the nodes so I'm trying to put it in the class.

Comment: When you say `Singleton`, do you specifically mean a [Godot Singleton](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html#singletons-autoload), i.e. an `Autoload` node?

Comment: Can you describe the flow of logic more clearly? Are you saying that when any recipe is launched, `after_launch` should be called in the noodles node?

Comment: Yes when I say Singleton, I mean Godot Singleton i,e an Autoload node. I'll edit my question with a flow.

Comment: You are right when you said after_launch or launched_recipename should be called in the noodles node - if that node is the one active on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Unexpected token Identifier:connect` occurs because `connect` is a function, so you need to call it within the scope of another function, like `_ready`. Based on the flow you describe, it sounds like `launched` should be a signal defined in the *cooking station*, not `recipe`, so you might have something like this:

- CookingStation (defines the signal `launched`)

  - Noodles (defines the function `_on_launched`)

In `Noodles.gd`:

```
extends Recipe

func _on_launched():
    print("Noodles was launched")

func _ready():
    var cooking_station = get_parent()
    cooking_station.connect("launched", self, "_on_launched")
```

There's really no need for a Singleton here. If you were thinking you needed a Singleton so `Noodles` could inherit from `Recipe`, it isn't necessary. Just adding the `class_name Recipe` directive will put `Recipe` in the global scope so other scripts can inherit from it.

Comment: Hi, this seemed to have work - but now I need to make separate signals for every type of recipe. Is there a way where I can make just one and make it work for all?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but maybe you want a parameterized signal? `signal launched(recipe_name)`, `emit_signal("launched", "noodles")`?

Comment: Yes, actually a parameterized signal might solve my problem - now that I think of it. Thank you, I'll do my research on signals with parameters.